# Image is appearing when running from live server but not appearing when running html file from my local path

Tags: html, css

The path, file name and file extensions are correct. So why is the image only showing up when on a live server?

This is the CSS code

```
#home {
 background-image: url("/images/2x/img-hero-image@2x.png");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 position: relative;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please show your code...

Comment: Try adding a dot before the path, like this - `"./images/2x/img-hero-image@2x.png"`

Comment: Let me know if this works or not!

Comment: It is not working..

Comment: Is there any error on the console ? Also, can you post picture of the directory?

Comment: Check the netwrok tab in the dev tools of the browser. What's the URL the browser is trying to fetch? Do you get a 404 or something there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my file load correctly through Live Server, but not through my browsers' support for the file:// protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75637309/why-does-my-file-load-correctly-through-live-server-but-not-through-my-browsers)

Answer (score 1):

Try to define the whole path from the root like

```
#home {
 background-image: url("C:/Users/yours/web/images/2x/img-hero-image@2x.png");
```

or define the path from the location html file like

```
#home {
 background-image: url("images/2x/img-hero-image@2x.png");
```

if you have to step back use `..` as well like

```
#home {
 background-image: url("../images/2x/img-hero-image@2x.png");
```

Comment: if it is live site can simply replace it with the domain